# output unable to write output in txt file

Tags: python

Steps:

- Read multiple .html files in the directory
- extract the titles of the html

Need:
- sending the titles into individual .txt files

Expected: Any advise. Ideally I wanted to extract integers from the html files name ('23434.html') and name the text files as '23434.txt'

Results:
- there is no txt file created in the designated path. 
- Nothing gets written

```
for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    with open(file_name) as html_file:
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html_file)
        d=soup.title.get_text()

        #resultfile=re.findall('\d+', file_name)

    with open("m"+".txt", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(d) 
        outfile.close
```

Comment: Your file `"m.txt"` (_sic!_) is created in the directory where you run the script. If you want to create it elsewhere, you must provide the full path.

Comment: Yes, sorry missed that part while posting earlier. thanks though. But what I do if I want to resultfile=re.findall('\d+', file_name) as the file names in the outfputfile. It will return me concatenation error.

Comment: This code seems to be perfect and if you don't see any errors on the terminal then it should work

Comment: thanks Arpit, I think 'basename' as suggested by inspectorG4get is more efficient way to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    with open(fpath) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
        html_title = soup.title.get_text()
        html_number = os.path.basename(fpath).rsplit('.',1)[0]

        with open(html_number + '.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(html_title)
```